# Specify the processing time of tasks fs2 streams Scala

Tags: scala, timer, queue, scheduling, fs2

I'm trying to process some tasks.
The time taken for the task may vary among elements. For instance, storing and getting the element `1`  from the queue may take 11seconds, while `2` may take 30 seconds...

I have tried using a timer for this but still, I'm getting the entryTime = ExitTime
I'm wondering what am I missing.

Here what I have tried :

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Timer}
import fs2._
import fs2.concurrent.Queue
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

class Tst(q1: Queue[IO, (Double, String, String)])(implicit timer: Timer[IO]) {

  import core.Processing._

  def storeInQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {

    Stream(1, 2, 3)
      .covary[IO]
      .evalTap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pushing $n to Queue")))
      .map { n =>
        val entryTime = currentTimeNow
        (n.toDouble, "Service", entryTime)
      //  timer.sleep(Random.between(10, 30).seconds) I have tried adding it here but the same result
       }
      .through(q1.enqueue)  
  }

      def getFromQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
        timer.sleep(Random.between(10, 30).seconds)
        q1.dequeue
          .map { n =>
            val exitTime = currentTimeNow
            (n._1, "Service", n._3, exitTime)
          }
          .evalMap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pulling from queue $n")))
      }
    }

    object Five2 extends IOApp {

      override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
        val program = for {
          q <- Queue.bounded[IO, (Double, String, String)](10)
          b = new Tst(q)
          _ <- b.storeInQueue.compile.drain.start

          _ <- b.getFromQueue.compile.drain

        } yield ()
        program.as(ExitCode.Success)
      }
    }
```

currentTimeNow method is given with :

```
def currentTimeNow: String = {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss")
    format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
  }
```

Comment: No It is not , I have edited the question and I have specified the implementation of currentTimeNow method.

Answer (score -1):

Got help from **gitter** : Here is thhe answer : 
There’s a couple of problems in the way you’re doing things there. Firstly, your `timer.sleep call` is ignored. *It is because it returns an IO, and IO will not do anything unless it is evaluated*. So you’d want to have it executed in your stream’s pipeline, which you could do with something like

```
q1.dequeue.evalTap(_ => timer.sleep(Random.between(10, 30).seconds))).map { n => … other things … }
```

Second thing is that I don’t know how your currentTimeNow function works, but normally in a functional stack obtaining the current time is an effectful operation, so using the timer you’d obtain the current time more like this:

```
Stream(1, 2, 3)
      .covary[IO]
      .evalTap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pushing $n to Queue")))
      .evalMap { n =>
        timer.clock.realTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map(entryTime => (n.toDouble, “Service”, entryTime))
      }
      .through(q1.enqueue)
```